# JSON field values become null after deserialization

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.ios

I have a JSON string like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "f4ba528a54117950",
    "type": "password-requests",
    "links": {
      "self": "https://api.abc.com/api/v2/password-requests/f4ba528a54117950"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "login": "abc",
      "type": "agent",
      "send-media": false,
      "registration-token": "ced84635eba"
    }
  }
}
```

My classes are like this

```
public  class SightCallResult
{
    public SightCallData data { get; set; }
}

public class SightCallData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> links { get; set; }
    public AgentAttributes attributes { get; set; }

}

public class AgentAttributes
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool SendMedia { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationToken { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I deserialize my string

```
sightCallRslt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SightCallResult>(resultMobileToken);
sightCallData = sightCallRslt.data;
agentAttributes = sightCallData.attributes;
Debug.WriteLine(agentAttributes.RegistrationToken);
```

But `RegistrationToken` is always null. But other field values are correctly assigned. Could anybody explain what would be the reason for this.

Comment: @PeterWishart did you mean to change the class attribute names to match with the key of the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the type of `attributes` to `Dictionary<string, object>`, or if you are sure there are a finite amount of possible attributes use the `JsonPropertyAttribute` to specify the exact names:

```
[JsonProperty("registration-token")]
public string RegistrationToken { get; set; }
```

Comment: It worked once I converted to Dictionary. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using `Newtonsoft.Json` which won't automatically map a hyphenated key name to a PascalCase key name.

You maybe didn't notice it for e.g. `send-media` because its a non nullable / defaults to false.

If you can't change the json, you can decorate the attributes with `JsonProperty`:

```
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="send-media")]
        public bool SendMedia { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="registration-token")]
        public string RegistrationToken { get; set; }
```

Comment: I changed my two attributes like this. But still its giving me that error :(. Any idea?